# How do you pass a TextEditingController value from a page to an action in Flutter using the async-redux package?

Tags: flutter, redux, async-redux

I am learning how to use the `async-redux` package in Flutter.

https://pub.dev/packages/async_redux

The samples are good for the most part, however rather simplistic. In particular, they show how to call an action from a page (i.e. how to hook a button up to an action via the `onPressed` event). This works great. However, they do not show how to pass a value from a page to the action. So I can fire a `save` event, but I cannot send it updated values from the page. I've boiled down my code to the code that follows.

Does anyone have any insight into how to read values from textControllers and pass them into the action? I am new to Flutter and the `async-redux` package and I'm having difficulty figuring out how it works.

For reference the code I provided is supposed to read first and last names from a form and send it to Firebase for storage (obviously the real-world app will be more involved than this).

Also, I have confirmed that the action is being reached because the `debugPrint()` statement in the `SaveSettingsAction` is executed.

```
import 'package:async_redux/async_redux.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart' show DragStartBehavior;
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Main method and app.
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
Store<AppState> store;

void main() {
  var state = AppState.initialState();
  store = Store<AppState>(initialState: state);
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StoreProvider<AppState>(
      store: store,
      child: MaterialApp(
        home: SettingsPage(),
        title: 'Sample App',
      )
    );
  }
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// App state.
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
class AppState {

  final String firstName;
  final String lastName;

  AppState({
    this.firstName,
    this.lastName,
  });

  AppState copy({String firstName, String lastName}) {
    return new AppState(
      firstName: firstName ?? this.firstName,
      lastName: lastName ?? this.lastName,
    );
  }

  static AppState initialState() => AppState(
    firstName: "",
    lastName: "",
  );

  @override
  int get hashCode =>
    firstName.hashCode ^
    lastName.hashCode;

  bool operator ==(Object other) =>
      identical(this, other) ||
          other is AppState &&
              runtimeType == other.runtimeType &&
              firstName == other.firstName &&
              lastName == other.lastName;

  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'AppState{'
        'firstName: $firstName,'
        'lastName: $lastName}';
  }
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Save settings action (ignore the persistence logic here - this is just a
// placeholder until we can read from the page properly).
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
class SaveSettingsAction extends ReduxAction<AppState> {
  final String firstName;
  final String lastName;

  SaveSettingsAction({this.firstName, this.lastName});

  @override
  Future<AppState> reduce() async {

    // Log that this action has been reached.
    debugPrint("Start of reduce function in SaveSettingsAction.");

    // Add values to Firebase (so we have history).
    Firestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .add({
      "firstName": firstName,
      "lastName": lastName,
    });

    // Return state with updated values.
    return state.copy(
      firstName: this.firstName,
      lastName: this.lastName,
    );
  }
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Settings connector.
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
class SettingsConnector extends StatelessWidget {
  SettingsConnector({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StoreConnector<AppState, SettingsViewModel>(
      model: SettingsViewModel(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, SettingsViewModel vm) => SettingsPage(
        firstName: vm.firstName,
        lastName: vm.lastName,
        onSaveSettings: vm.onSaveSettings,
      ),
    );
  }
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Settings view model.
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
class SettingsViewModel extends BaseModel<AppState> {
  SettingsViewModel();

  String firstName;
  String lastName;
  VoidCallback onSaveSettings;

  SettingsViewModel.build({
    @required this.firstName,
    @required this.lastName,
    @required this.onSaveSettings,
  }) : super (equals: [firstName, lastName]);

  @override
  SettingsViewModel fromStore() => SettingsViewModel.build(
    firstName: state.firstName,
    lastName: state.lastName,
    onSaveSettings: () => dispatch(SaveSettingsAction()),
  );
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Settings page.
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
class SettingsPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final String firstName;
  final String lastName;
  final VoidCallback onSaveSettings;

  final TextEditingController firstNameController;
  final TextEditingController lastNameController;

  SettingsPage({
    Key key,
    this.firstName,
    this.lastName,
    this.onSaveSettings,
    this.firstNameController,
    this.lastNameController,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Scrollbar(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              dragStartBehavior: DragStartBehavior.down,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 4.0),
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    TextFormField(
                      controller: firstNameController,
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.person),
                        labelText: 'First Name',
                      ),
                      initialValue: firstName,
                    ),
                    TextFormField(
                      controller: lastNameController,
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.person),
                        labelText: 'Last Name',
                      ),
                      initialValue: lastName,
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16.0),
                      child: RaisedButton(
                        // How do we get the textController values to the onSaveSettings action?
                        onPressed: onSaveSettings,
                        child: const Text(
                            'Save Settings',
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16)
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Are You looking for `lastNameController.text`? `text` has the value typed in a `TextField` with  `lastNameController` as its controller.

Comment: Thanks NoobN3rd - reading from the controller isn't the tricky part (sorry if that was the impression I gave). The issue is how to pass those values (or any values) from the page to the action. Any ideas?

Comment: sorry for misunderstanding, Honestly I didn't work with `async-redux`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for being 7 months late. :(

This answer is the same for AsyncRedux or any other Redux version:

Instead of:

```dart
final VoidCallback onSaveSettings;
```

It should be:

```dart
final void Function(String firstName, String lastName) onSaveSettings;
```

Or, if you want to use a typedef:

```dart
typedef OnSaveSettings = void Function(String firstName, String lastName);
...

final OnSaveSettings onSaveSettings;
```

And then you pass the first and last names to the callback:

```dart
RaisedButton(
   onPressed: () => onSaveSettings(
      firstNameController.text, 
      lastNameController.text,
   ),
   ...
```

The view-model should be:

```dart
@override
SettingsViewModel fromStore() => SettingsViewModel.build(
    firstName: state.firstName,
    lastName: state.lastName,
    onSaveSettings: (firstName, lastName) => dispatch(SaveSettingsAction(firstName, lastName)),
);
```

*Note: I am the author of the AsyncRedux package.*

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer this. Your explanation is very good. I had since figured this out, lol, but this is useful nonetheless. Thanks for your contributions to the Flutter ecosystem as well.